# python regular expression remove matching brackets file

Tags: python, regex

I have a Latex file where a lot of text is marked with `\red{}`, but there may also be brackets inside the `\red{}`, like `\red{here is \underline{underlined} text}`. I want to remove the red color and after some googling I wrote this python script:

```
import os, re, sys
#Start program in terminal with
#python RedRemover.py filename
#sys.argv[1] then has the value filename
ifn = sys.argv[1]
#Open file and read it
f = open(ifn, "r")
c = f.read() 
#The whole file content is now stored in the string c
#Remove occurences of \red{...} in c
c=re.sub(r'\\red\{(?:[^\}|]*\|)?([^\}|]*)\}', r'\1', c)
#Write c into new file
Nf=open("RedRemoved_"+ifn,"w")
Nf.write(c)

f.close()
Nf.close()
```

But this will convert

> \red{here is \underline{underlined} text}

to

> here is \underline{underlined text}

which is not what I want. I want

> here is \underline{underlined} text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't match an undetermined level of nested brackets with the re module since it doesn't support recursion. To solve that, you can use the [new regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
import regex

c = r'\red{here is \underline{underlined} text}'

c = regex.sub(r'\\red({((?>[^{}]+|(?1))*)})', r'\2', c)
```

Where `(?1)` is a recursive call to the capture group 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Had to do a pip install regex, then it worked like a charm.

Comment: @user2609987: It is indeed not installed by default.

Comment: @ridgerunner:Thanks. The curly brackets don't need to be escaped as often when the context is not ambiguous (i.e. when there are no integer or couple of integers surrounded by curly brackets). Many flavors don't consider the closing curly bracket as a special character. The capture group 2 is used for the replacement.

Comment: Nice answer. +1 (but I'd still escape those curly braces. :^)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to keep the curlies, consider this case: `\red{\bf test}`:

```
import re

c = r'\red{here is \underline{underlined} text} and \red{more}'
d = c 

# this may be less painful and sufficient, and even more correct
c = re.sub(r'\\red\b', r'', c)
print "1ST:", c

# if you want to get rid of the curlies:
d = re.sub(r'\\red{([^{]*(?:{[^}]*}[^}]*)*)}', r'\1', d)
print "2ND:", d
```

*Gives:*

```
1ST: {here is \underline{underlined} text} and {more}
2ND: here is \underline{underlined} text and more
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this won't work if there are several occurrences of red text, like in     c = r'\red{here is \underline{underlined} text} and \red{more}'

Comment: Thanks. I also appreciate the comment about keeping the curly brackets, but in my file the case you mentioned does not occur.